# How to send commands on behalf of another user with slack api

Tags: python, api, slack

I am building a Slack app which is similar to the [`fuck`](https://github.com/EricFreeman/fuck) command line tool. It's supposed to find typos of users trying to execute a command and execute the correct command on their behalf.

I searched a lot and find unofficial document about the [`chat.command`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md) api which is useful, but I need to send a command as another user. The approach I am taking right now is to ask the user for his or her legacy token on the channel, then save it on db for sending commands on behalf of them. But it's not practical

```
slack.legacy_client.api_call(
   "chat.command",
    channel='channel_id',
    command='/command',
    text='do stuff',
)
```

Is there a better way to send command on behalf of another user?

Comment: I highly doubt you'll be able to do this since it could quite easily be abused

Comment: I think that would only work if you had a legacy token from every user

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to do this is to, as you say, save off the token. Otherwise there's no way that Slack will know that you are able to execute as the other use. As part of installing the application, you might add a configuration step that each user will have to go through to set up the tool, and save off the token there.

You can use the database, as you suggest. Another alternative is to use a platform like Tranposit (full disclosure, I'm employed there). They've built a system to store off users' tokens (for Slack and other APIs, though Slack is the relevant API here). More info here: https://www.transposit.com/docs/building/managed-authentication/